# Why does it seem like websites can still use JavaScript in Chrome after disabling JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, chrome

I have disabled JavaScript under "Site settings" in Chrome. That is, I selected: "Don't allow sites to use Javascript". After doing so, I encountered a webpage that somehow manages to refresh itself every 5 seconds, seemingly by using JavaScript. The page source was:

```
<html><body>
<script>{setInterval(function(){document.location.reload();},5000)}</script>
<div>
[...]
```

How come it was able to use JavaScript? (I confirmed the "JavaScript blocked" status on that page.)

Comment: Did it have a `<meta refresh ... >` tag?

Comment: @CBHacking no. If you go to [https://archive.md](https://archive.md), it's the page you see after clicking "save" to archive a url (i.e. it's the page you see while waiting for it to complete).

Comment: @anon_wh1 so, it *did* have a `<meta refresh ... >` tag?

Comment: @schroeder It did not have that tag. But it did use "HTTP refresh header".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that JavaScript was actually blocked successfully, and what I observed was accomplished via ["HTTP refresh header"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL_redirection#Refresh_Meta_tag_and_HTTP_refresh_header).

Comment: Can you expand on how this bypasses the blocking of Javascript?

Comment: @schroeder JavaScript was blocked successfully and was not used here (what caused the refresh was a different thing: HTTP refresh header). I edited my answer to make that clear.